Automated theorem proving and set theory
I already know a few things about theorem proving however I was wondering how to use this when we are dealing with a non finite amount of axioms. In particular I was hoping to understand how to use automated theorem proving for set theory like ZFC for example.
The method I know is using sequent calculus and the cut elimination theorem, thus we are able to build a simple system of logical rules that are only introduction rules. Thus if we have a sequent $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ we can apply those rules backwards (we may need to do so several times due to quantifier "problems") and eventually end up with a set $S$ of sequents. Then we use a unification algorithm on some variables in $S$ (which represent the terms we need to choose) to obtain a substitution $\sigma$ such that $S[\sigma]$ contains only sequents that are instances of a certain modified axiom rules which contains the weakening rules. If this succeeds then we the procedure yields a proof of $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$. And if $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ is provable this procedure will eventually succeed.
Now for any theory $T$ that contains a finite number of axioms there is no problem because if we want to prove $T \vdash \Delta$ we can simply apply this. However for example in ZFC we have an infinite number of axioms, indeed there is a set of axioms like so:
$$\forall x, \exists y, \forall z (z \in y \iff (z \in x \land F(z)))$$
Where $F$ can be any formula (there are some restrictions but still there are an infinite number of such formulas), thus I am not sure how one can adapt the procedure described above to this problem. My main problem is "guessing" this $F$. Because in order to have that $ZFC \vdash \Delta$ we need to find a finite set of axioms $\Gamma$ in ZFC such that $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$.
If you have a reference on this topic I would be very happy to know it. I am not working in this field but my project would be on my free time to program this kind of procedure in C++ or something.

Well, you can always use $\mathsf{NBG}$ which is a finitely-axiomatizable conservative extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Indeed, in a precise sense every ("non-silly") theory has a conservative finitely-axiomatizable extension; see here. Here "non-silly" has two aspects: we need to avoid too complicated theories, and we need to avoid theories with boring models. Both conditions apply to $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Sorry, it looks like I accidentally thumbed a downvote on this question while bookmarking it (the joys of using Math.SE on a phone). Can you make a dummy edit so that I can undo it?

I am not sure what you are asking, the usual tools are proof assistants, not (yet?) automated provers, especially considering that "[d]epending on the underlying logic, the problem of deciding the validity of a formula varies from trivial to impossible" (Automated theorem proving - WP).  Indeed, you say "this procedure will eventually succeed": what does "eventually" even mean there?  E.g. by Goedel's incompleteness we are guaranteed that some theorems of arithmetic are not reachable from the axioms of arithmetic...

@NoahSchweber Thank you, I will definitely check out NBG, from what I understand you are saying that this theory is larger than ZFC but only has a finite number of axioms? And I guess that the "conservative" means that if we have a proof of a ZFC statement in NBG then there exists a proof in ZFC?

@JulioDiEgidio What I am asking is that if a sequent is provable then the procedure gives the proof. This does not contradict Goedel's incompleteness theorem because we have no bounds on the time it will take to compute the proof. So if the statement is not provable it will never stop computing. And if it is it can take a very very long time to compute. So in general this can not be used to know if a statement is provable or not. But if this procedure eventually finishes you know that your sequent is provable.

@LeGrandSpectacle  Thanks for clarifying.  I am under the impression that you risk to be conflating the underlying "language" (or "logic"), e.g. a sequent calculus, with a "theory", e.g. a set theory, that is written in that language, namely axioms then (derived) theorems.  Indeed, that is where I do not see an immediate connection: but I might just be missing the technical point of the conversation here, I am not sure...

As far as I understood, you want to find the solution F of the unification equation F(t) ~ P where t is a term and P is a formula. Am I right?

@JulioDiEgidio I am not sure I understand what you are saying. But basically if we forget about ZFC, there is an procedure that is able to search for a proof of $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$, in particular this is also true if $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are written in the language of ZFC. But the problem is that I would like to be able to prove a statement $F$ in ZFC, this means that I must find $\Gamma \subset ZFC$ such that $\Gamma \vdash F$ is provable. The problem arises because I need to find a correct $\Gamma$, if ZFC were finite one could just try to prove the sequent $ZFC \vdash F$.

@KijeongLim Yes that would definitely be a step forward.

@NoahSchweber By the way I was wondering if NBG also contains the axioms for equality, because if I remember correctly ZFC does not and the axioms needed for equality are also infinite.

@LeGrandSpectacle The rules governing equality are part of the basic apparatus of first-order logic; they're "for free." For example, $\emptyset\vdash \forall x,y(x=y\rightarrow y=x)$ and so on.

@NoahSchweber well i know the equality rules for natural deduction but not for sequent calculus, I would be happy to know them though. The book I am reading elaborated the theory of automated proving without considering equality to be part of the logical rules. The author said that it could be added as axioms if necessary (instead of using logic rules). For some reason I thought that there would be infinity many axioms for defining equality but after checking I stand corrected: if we have finitely many function and relation symbols there will be finitely many axioms for defining equality.

Let me ask once again. If P is 0 = 0 and t is 0, then the only solutions F(z) to the equation F(t) ~ P are z = z, z = 0, 0 = z, and 0 = 0. Do you want to know how to find them? If so, I have a very nice solution.

@KijeongLim Yes of course please let me know!

A logic programming language $\lambda \mathrm{Prolog}$ is the perfect solution. Get the book Programming with Higher-Order Logic written by Dale Miller and Gopalan Nadathur, and read section 7.6. Although I want to answer, my English is not good enough for writting long text... I'm sorry for that.

You might want to read John Harrison's Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning, which works through the implementation of algorithms used by proof assistants in first-order logic.
You just add some axioms for ZFC (or NBG, or...), then you're off to the races.
There are other references you could use to complement Harrison's book (I've written a brief literature review).
